# how to paste a constant block of code in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

The requirement is to create a constant and save it in vscode and assign a shortcut to it and whenever the shortcut is used the stored block of code gets pasted automatically.

For example:
the below code is something that i need to add in multiple files

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = [1,2,3,4,5]
    print(fun(s))
```

So, i need to store this in one place just once in vscode and assign a shortcut key to it, next time using the shortcut key the codeblock should get pasted as it is.
Also, would not want the content currently copied on clipboard to be affected.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Something like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wdawson.better-kill-ring might work for you.  I haven't checked it to see if it clobbers the Clipboard.  It shouldn't need to.

Comment: just type `__name__` and VSC will suggest the `if` line

Comment: you can use [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates) to create skeleton file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with the **Snippets**. Create any code snippet you like, then add a keyboard shortcut to it. It gives the ability to not only insert snippet by a shortcut but also with a prefix (for example 'ifmain').

First, you create code snippet. Navigate to **File** > **Preferences** > **User snippets** > **python.json** (or ctrl+shift+p 'configure user snippets'). Create any snippet here (in json syntax), then save the file.
Example of snippet for code you provided:

```
{
  "if name main": {
    "prefix": "ifmain",
    "body": [
      "if __name__ == '__main__':",
      "    s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]",
      "    print(fun(s))"
    ],
    "description": "my cool snippet"
  }
}
```

Secondly, you add a keyboard shortcut to snippet. **File** > **Preferences** > **Keyboard shortcuts** (ctrl+k ctrl+s). Then click small icon located on top right corner named 'Open Keyboard Shortcuts', as shown here:

[image: Screenshot]

Add shortcut to the insert snippet command then save the file. Example:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+k 1",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
    "langId": "python",
    "name": "if name main"
}
```

Press **ctrl+k 1** > it will insert snippet. Start typing '**ifmain**' then smash **Tab** > it will insert snippet.